# Apple Watch animation broke after 1.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, watchkit

I had an animation in a `WKInterfaceImage` within a `WKInterfaceTable` :

```
[[self.table setNumberOfRows:1 withRowType:@"Loading"];
WatchLoadingCell *cell = [self.table rowControllerAtIndex:0];

[cell.image setImageNamed:@"spin"];
[cell.image startAnimating];
```

My images are named `spin0` - `spin30` and are added to the watchKit App target.

when the app runs, the image is static, i.e only showing `spin0`

any ideas why?

EDIT: it works in the simulator, but not on the device itself, it works on the device only when I reload the view by calling `[self awakeWithContext:nil];` from my Force Touch menu

I have also tried starting the animation in `willActivate` with no luck

Answer (score 2):

When setting animation images in code, you should use startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:duration:repeatCount: method

```
[cell.image setImageNamed:@"spin"];
[cell.image startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 30) duration:10 repeatCount:0];
```

If you call startAnimating method, duration set in IB will be used

[IB-screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23696295/watchkit-animation.png)

Comment: Looks like resources copying issue. Have you tried removing animation frames from your project and adding them again or moving them to watch app asset catalog?

Comment: yep, all images are included. it seems to just not animate when awakeWithContext is called for the first time - I have a force touch gesture that calls awakeWithContext to refresh, the animation works in this situation

Comment: Oh, guess `awakeWithContext` isn't the right place to start animation. Try to move it in your controller's `willActivate`. Refer to WatchKit App Life Cycle at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html